# How to negate regex in pymongo

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

Is it possible to negate a regex in pymongo? I want to get documents whose `date` field is not of the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I've tried

```
regex = '/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/' 
col.find({'date': {'$not': re.compile(regex)}}, {'_id': 0, 'date': 1})
```

but it doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negating the `^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$`  pattern means you want to match any string that does not conform to that pattern.

You may use a negative lookahead based regex and use it without any negations inside code:

```
^(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$)
```

Since the pattern is used to match strings partially, this pattern will do the job finding the starting positions in strings that do not start with 4 digits, `-`, 2 digits, `-` and 2 digits followed with the end of string marker.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y6iQsA/2).

To disallow empty matches, add a `.` at the end of the pattern.